# grep lines matching a pattern, and the lines before and after the matching

Tags: perl, grep

I would like to do a pattern matching on a file (about 200 MegaBytes) and then push in an array the matching lines and also an arbitrary number of lines before and after each matching line.

sub1, using perl grep, takes 11 seconds

sub2, which uses unix egrep, 1 second

sub6 (ack) 50 seconds (it is faster if you don't use \b, \s anchors etc)

ack from the command line takes 15 seconds

**I'm interested in suggestions to speed up the sub1, or to find a fast perl solution that does not rely on external tools**

It seems that perl grep is much slower than the unix one.

"index" is really faster than regexes (but I need the \b, \s etc)

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=885174

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=957554

thanks

```
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep ualarm gettimeofday tv_interval);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

open FILE, '<textMatchInAfile.txt' or die;
my $p = '\bsala|che|relazione|di|questo|coso|^qui\$';
my $mR = 1;        #print more rows before - after the matching
my @n  = <FILE>;

&sub1( $p, $mR, @n );    #suggest: insert references
&sub3( $p, $mR );

sub sub1 {               #questa sub usa perl grep
my $p    = $_[0];             #pattern
my $mR   = $_[1];             #more rows
my @n    = @_[ 2 .. $#_ ];    #input File
my $time = [gettimeofday];
my @new = grep { $n[$_] =~ /$p/ } 0 .. $#n;
my @unique =
  map { @n[ $_ - $mR .. $_ + $mR ] } @new[ 0 + $mR .. $#new - $mR];
say "\n" . 'time sub1 perl grep: ' . tv_interval($time);
@unique = uniq(@unique);
say "sub 1 $#unique";
}

sub sub3 {    #unix grep with color and line numbers
my $p   = $_[0];
my $mR  = $_[1];
my $cmd = "grep -n -C $mR";    #with line numbers
$p =~ s/\|/ /g;
$p =~ s/\h+/" -e "/g;
$p = ' -e "' . $p . '" ';
say "cmd ===$cmd=== ss ===$p===";
my @values;
$values[0] = $p;
$values[1] = ( ' ' . 'textMatchInAfile.txt' );    
my $time = [gettimeofday];
my @valori = `$cmd @values` or die "system @values` failed: $?";
say 'sub3 egrep shell: ' . $#valori;
say 'time sub3 tempo trovati con egrep shell ' . tv_interval($time);
my @uniq_list = uniq(@valori);
}

sub sub6 {             #perl ack
my $p  = $_[0];    #pattern
my $mR = $_[1];    #more rows
my @values;
my $time   = [gettimeofday];
my @valori = qx (ack -C $mR "$p" textMatchInAfile.txt)
  or die "system @values` failed: $?";
say 'number of values found with ack' . $#valori;
say 'time sub6 ack' . tv_interval($time);
}
```

#

```
#this one takes 11 seconds

 use 5.014;
 use warnings;
 use Time::HiRes qw(usleep ualarm gettimeofday tv_interval);

 my @array;
 my $pattern = '\bsala|che|relazione|di|questo|coso|^qui\$';
 open( my $filehandle, "<textMatchInAfile.txt" );
 my $time = [gettimeofday];
 while (<$filehandle>) {
     if ( $_ =~ /$pattern/ ) {
    push @array;
     }
 }
 say 'time while' . tv_interval($time);
```

---

Ok ok, unix grep is an order of magnitude faster that perl grep, I'll live with that.

Comment: I recommend using [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) module. I find your code a bit hard to read and it's difficult to write my own code because I'd need some sample of your input data. But as far as I can see you're loading the whole content of the file into an array. Better do a `while` loop and process the file line by line. After all Perl should be nearly equally fast as unix tools with pipes *after compilation* which might take some time (insignificant for larger amounts of input data).

Comment: My input data is simply generic text prose. I've found out there is no way to compete with the speed of unix grep, I think that I've tried all the possible approaches

Comment: Well, I tried to write my own sub for that problem (just for the fun of it) with some data made up but it's impossible because I definitely cannot understand what your code is actually doing. Considering the quality and efficiency of your example subs I am pretty sure there's still much space for optimization in your code. But nobody will tell you unless you provide some data and describe what you actually want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure there is not much space for optimization, the sub that uses unix grep will always be about 10 times faster, I've tried many different solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Why don you use grep -B 1 -A 1?

That give you the exact output you need.

```
grep -B 1 -A 1 -E patter file
```

Regards,

Comment: The grep was already included in the orginal post, but I would prefer a perl solution

Comment: Ok, I've seen that unix grep is an order of magnitude faster that perl grep, there's no code optimization that can overturn it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some basic comparison of Unix' `egrep` and Perl's `grep` command, the latter with two different implementations.

```
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $count = $ARGV[0] || 100;

my $re = "L[aeiou]n*.?[xyz]\\b";

cmpthese($count, {
    unix => sub {
        my $result = `dmesg|egrep '$re'`;

        #print "===unix===\n";
        #print $result;
    },
    perl => sub {
        my @result = grep {$_ =~ m/$re/} split m/\n/, `dmesg`;

        #print "===perl===\n";
        #map {print "$_\n"} @result;
    },
    perl2 => sub {
        open(DMESG, "dmesg|" ) or die "cannot open dmesg pipe!";

        my @result;

        while(<DMESG>) {
            push @result, $_ if m/$re/;
        }

        #print "===perl2===\n";
        #map {print} @result;

        close DMESG;
    },
});
```

Result:

```
$ perl grep.pl 1000
        Rate  unix  perl perl2
unix  24.6/s    --  -40%  -44%
perl  41.0/s   67%    --   -6%
perl2 43.6/s   77%    6%    --
```

So please explain why Perl's grep is naturally slower than Unix `grep`.

PS I adapted the script to run on a file with 25k lines of random data and a different RE. That scenario is bit more similar to yours.

```
$ perl tmp/grep.pl 1000
        Rate  unix  perl perl2
unix  3.71/s    --  -32%  -44%
perl  5.50/s   48%    --  -17%
perl2 6.64/s   79%   21%    --
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, sorry but is is slower...  

    my $re = '\bsala|che|relazione|di|questo|coso|^qui\$';  

    Press ENTER or type command to continue  
         Rate  perl perl2  unix  
     perl  28.6/s    --   -5%  -76%  
     perl2 29.9/s    5%    --  -75%  
     unix   118/s  312%  293%    --